# Upgrade Paths in Wix

Tags: wix, upgrade

Is it possible to specify Upgrade Paths in Major Upgrade? For example, let's say if a client is at version 1.3 or 1.4, they can upgrade to 2.0, but if they are in 1.1 or 1.2, they must first upgrade to 1.3 or 1.4 before upgrading to 2.0? How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the [`<Upgrade>`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/upgrade.html) tag to implement this properly using the `OnlyDetect` and `Minimum`, `Maximum`, `IncludeMinimum`, and `IncludeMaximum`  values.

You will need an `OnlyDetect='no'` that will actually do the correct upgrade for the versions it supports and other `<Upgrade>` definition(s) which set properties which you have launch conditions associated with that have appropriate error messages like

> "This installation is only valid for upgrading `<product>` versions a.x and a.y please update to one of these versions and rerun this installation."

But, supporting this kind of tiered upgrade approach can bite you in the butt if you aren't careful with it so use caution and double check your conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response Brian. So, will this work only with Minor Upgrades or it will work with Major Upgrades also? Also, there doesn't seem to be good documentation / tutorials on how to achieve this? It will be great, if you can please provide some links also.

Comment: @ven: Example here https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/checking-for-oldies/ and use OnlyDetect=yes for detecting invalid versions, use the property in the launch conditions.  This is major upgrades as you asked.